# How to interpret bytes for UTF-8 encoded Hiragana?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, cjk

I have a string "はい" and I'm trying to understand how it's represented as bytes.

```
Number.prototype.toBits = function () {
    let str = this.toString(2);
    return str.padStart(8, "0");
}
let ja = "はい";
console.log(ja);
let buf = Buffer.from(ja);
for (const c of buf) {
    console.log(c + "=" + c.toBits());
}
```

produces:

```
はい
227=11100011
129=10000001
175=10101111
227=11100011
129=10000001
132=10000100
```

In the Unicode table, the character "は" is 306F and the character "い" is 3044.

I understand that the leading "1" bit says this is Unicode and that the number of 1s until the next 0 is the number of bytes in Unicode.  I don't understand how 306F becomes 11100011 10000001 10101111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description), code points between U+0800 and U+FFFF (which U+306F meets) will be encoded as 3 bytes, spreading their bits across the pattern

```
  1110.... 10...... 10......
```

The binary representation of 0x306F is 0b11000001101111, which fits in the gaps:

```
| ....0011 ..000001 ..101111
```

Together, they form what you are observing:

```
= 11100011 10000001 10101111
```

Comment: Ok.  I see it it now.  Each character is 4 bits but each byte has a header to indicate that it's Unicode and how many bytes long it is.

Comment: @R OMS: not really. UTF8 is just an encoding, there is not much semantic in it, but: being efficient to encode Unicode strings, and to easily and quickly find where a new character starts (thing about going in middle of a file, without needing to parse all characters, like e..g for old UTF-7). You may find more semantic in unicode code point (but because history/old design/missing characters) it is also not so simple [think about few obsolete hiragana characters]

Answer (score 3):

The fact that the most-significant bit (MSB) is `1` indicates that it's a UTF-8 multibyte sequence.  If the first two bits are `11` then it's the *start* of a sequence; if `10` it's the *continuation* of a sequence. Bits of the actual code point are stored in the "unused" portion of both start-bytes and continuation-bytes; as many bytes as are necessary to store the value (and, as indicated by the start-byte).

Notice how it is possible to "drop in anywhere" in the byte-sequence and align yourself to the start of a character:  if `MSB=0` then it's a single-byte character (ASCII-compatible). If `MSBs=10` it's a continuation byte and you should walk-backwards to find the start byte.  The start-byte should always be followed by exactly the number of continuation-bytes that it promises.  UTF encodings use exactly the number of bytes needed to represent any given Unicode code-point.